# How to Azure SQL Server Column DataType Length Should be Migrate into Spark SQL supported

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

We are trying to migrate azure SQL into spark supported SQL but there is discrepancy while migrate SQL views, there is column data type length not matched with spark SQL, so that our SAS reports getting error while compared to azure SQL vs spark SQL data.

please sample data type length for all your reference.

```
Azure SQL                             Spark SQL
column1 nvarchar(5)                   column1 string
startdate datetime2                   startdate timestamp
enddate datetime2(0)                  enddate timestamp
```

Comment: Can you fill in the details of how the data "migrated"?

Comment: in Azure SQL we have like select column1 nvarchar(1), testdate datetime2, column3 datetime2(0) from tablename

Comment: df = spark.sql(""" select cast(column1 as varchar(1), cast(testdate as timestamp), cast(column3 as timestamp) from tablename """)

Comment: df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteschema","true").option("path",'/mnt/test/tablename').saveAsTable("tablename")

Comment: on top of that path we created unity catalog table

Comment: azure sql data type lenght for example nvarchar(1), it will be like 1 memory taking from SAS reports.. if use spark sql table string or varchar(1), by default 255 length taking. this is issues blocking SAS reports BI reports tool. how should I handle at spark end

Answer (score 0):

According to [Data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datatypes), you can specify the length of a **String** column by using the **String** Datatype.

However, as you mentioned that you are having an issue with **SAS** reports BI reports tool, I tried a source data like below:

**Source data:**

[image]

I have tried the below approach using `spark.sql`:

```py
maxLen =  5
colName =  "column1"
spark.sql(f"""
    INSERT INTO trial_01
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN LENGTH({colName}) > {maxLen} THEN SUBSTR({colName}, 1, {maxLen}) ELSE {colName} END as {colName},
        startdate,
        enddate
    FROM source_table
""")
```

**Results:**

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|column1|          startdate|            enddate|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  hijkl|2024-03-02 12:00:00|2024-03-03 12:00:00|
|  abcde|2024-03-01 12:00:00|2024-03-02 12:00:00|
|    xyz|2024-03-03 12:00:00|2024-03-04 12:00:00|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Defining the maximum length and column name, this query uses a `CASE` statement to determine if the length of the `colName` column exceeds `maxLen`. If it does, the `SUBSTR` function is used to extract the first `maxLen` characters of `colName`. If the length is not exceeded, the original colName is retained. The `AS {colName}` part ensures that the modified column retains the original column name.

You can also check the reference for a similar issue in SCALA in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823587/is-there-a-way-to-limit-string-length-in-a-spark-dataframe-type) link here.

**2nd approach:**

In Databricks SQL, you can enforce a specific length for a column using a constraint. After creating the table, you can use the **ADD CONSTRAINT** parameter in the **ALTER TABLE** statement.

For instance, you can create a table with a `STRING` column and add a constraint to ensure that the column always contains exactly 34 characters.

Below is the example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table (
  iban STRING
);

ALTER TABLE new_table ADD CONSTRAINT IBAN1 CHECK (length(IBAN) = 34);
```

When I tried the below, it gave me an error:

```sql
insert into new_table (IBAN) values ('09')
```

```
InvariantViolationException: CHECK constraint iban1 (length(IBAN) = 34) violated by row with values:
 - IBAN : 09
```

This will enforce that any value inserted into the iban column must have exactly 34 characters.

```sql
insert into new_table (IBAN) values ("1234567890123456789012345678901234")
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Good idea, but an exact length , like the 34 in your example, is probably not a good idea. Can the constraint use an inequality?  Like `CHECK (length(IBAN) <= 34)`?  That is a more practical example.

Comment: even if i tried above steps still i can n't reduced size and getting default length 255 for string data type and datetime2 and datetime2(0) 25 length

Comment: @DeveloperKE Are you connecting your Spark SQL table direct to Power Bi to build reports?

Comment: no, we are calling data vault table to query the data and write back to adls then on top of that unity catalog created external table like that

Comment: My idea is as you are having issue with the databricks unity catalog tables with their datatypes you can create a view in the Synapse and then connect the view to power BI so you can limit the memory of the datatypes.